# Получение номера телефона из контактов

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
Мне необходимо получить номер телефона из контактов через `Intent`. Я получаю их так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Проблема в том, что если в контакте указано несколько номеров, берется первый - пользователь не может выбрать из них.
Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ, я использовал такой код:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); 
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, 1);
```